# PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code when archiving only

Tags: xcode, flutter, cocoapods, app-store, archive

Stuck for a week and yet can't find a solution I did everything but I can't archive the is to submit it to AppStore. It runs on Simulator smoothly with no issues but when I click archive the below error return

```
PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/auser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-evxpqziwqhmcfdeqitqdevhmsglz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    cd /Users/auser/Documents/Mobile\ Apps/Flutter/flutterproj/ios
    export ACTION\=install
    export AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED\=NO
    export ALLOW_TARGET_PLATFORM_SPECIALIZATION\=NO
    export ALTERNATE_GROUP\=staff
    export ALTERNATE_MODE\=u+w,go-w,a+rX
    export ALTERNATE_OWNER\=username
    export ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES\=YES
    export ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS\=NO
    export ALWAYS_USE_SEPARATE_HEADERMAPS\=NO
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_DEVELOPER_DIR\=/AppleInternal/Developer
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_DIR\=/AppleInternal
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_DOCUMENTATION_DIR\=/AppleInternal/Documentation
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_LIBRARY_DIR\=/AppleInternal/Library
    export APPLE_INTERNAL_TOOLS\=/AppleInternal/Developer/Tools
    export APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY\=NO
    export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_FILES\=NO
    export APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_HEADERS\=NO
    export ARCHS_STANDARD\=arm64
    export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_64_BIT\=armv7\ arm64
    export ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT\=armv7
    export ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT\=arm64
    export ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT\=arm64
    export ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS\=armv7\ arm64
    export ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME\=AppIcon
    export ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_FLATTENED_APP_ICON_PATH\=/Users/auser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-evxpqziwqhmcfdeqitqdevhmsglz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProductsPath/ProductIcon.png
    export ASSET_PACK_FOLDER_PATH\=/Users/auser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-evxpqziwqhmcfdeqitqdevhmsglz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/OnDemandResources
    export variant\=normal
    /bin/sh -c /Users/auser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-evxpqziwqhmcfdeqitqdevhmsglz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh


Failed to package /Users/auser/Documents/Mobile Apps/Flutter/flutterproj.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

My Podfile code:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

The flutter pubspec.yaml

```
name: application_name
description: Application Description


publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.4.1
  firebase_messaging: ^14.2.1
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.11.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^13.0.0
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.16
  flutter_offline: ^2.1.0
  internet_connection_checker: ^1.0.0+1
  url_launcher: ^6.1.7
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

flutter_icons:
  image_path_android: "assets/playstore.png"
  image_path_ios: "assets/appstore.png"
  android: true
  ios: true
  remove_alpha_ios: true
  adaptive_icon_background: "#fff"

flutter_native_splash:
  #image: ""
  image: assets/splash_screen.jpg
  background_image: assets/splash_screen.jpg
  #color: ""
  android: true
  ios: true
  ios_content_mode: scaleToFill

  android_12:
    image: assets/splash_screen.jpg
    icon_background_color: "#BD081B"
```

I m using Xcode 14.2, MacOS Ventura 13.2, pod 1.11.3, ruby 3.0.2p107

Build Phase Screenshots
[image: Thin Binary]
[image: Embed Pods Framework]
[image: Cop Bundle Resources]
[image: Link Binnary with Libraries]
[image: Run Script]

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue before the solution was to downgrade (or install an older version of xcode) back then the issue was resolved by installing Xcode 13.2, I believe now MacOS prevents any old versions (older than 14). the issue might not be from your code, it might be from a package not compatible with the xcode building process.

Answer (score -1):

what worked for me was to use ccleaner to wipe out every piece of junk in my mac. it worked just fine after that